# AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'Text1'

Tags: python, tkinter

My purpose is to get the mouse selected text through the Tkinter `Text` control.

Part of the code:

```
self.Text1 = Text(top)
self.Text1.place(relx=0.07, rely=0.09, relheight=0.04, relwidth=0.34)
self.Text1.configure(background="white")
self.Text1.configure(font="TkTextFont")
self.Text1.configure(foreground="black")
self.Text1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
self.Text1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
self.Text1.configure(insertbackground="black")
self.Text1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
self.Text1.configure(selectforeground="black")
self.Text1.configure(width=294)
self.Text1.configure(wrap=WORD)

self.Scrolledtext1 = ScrolledText(top)
self.Scrolledtext1.place(relx=0.46, rely=0.19, relheight=0.62
        , relwidth=0.4)
self.Scrolledtext1.configure(background="white")
self.Scrolledtext1.configure(font="TkTextFont")
self.Scrolledtext1.configure(foreground="black")
self.Scrolledtext1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
self.Scrolledtext1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
self.Scrolledtext1.configure(insertbackground="black")

def button_down(self,):
    global s
    s = self.Text1.index('@%s,%s wordstart' % (event.x, event.y))

def button_up(self, ):
    global e
    e = self.Text1.index('@%s,%s wordend' % (event.x, event.y))


def test(self,):
    print(self.Scrolledtext1.get(s,e))

self.Scrolledtext1.bind("<Button-1>", button_down)
self.Scrolledtext1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", button_up)
self.Button2.configure(command=test(self,))
```

Exception in Tkinter callback：

[screenshot of traceback showing exception being generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2012.png)

```
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'Text1'
```

Comment: You are omitting code that is relevant for an answer. Such as your class definition and the global event.

Comment: Tkinter automatically passes an `Event` argument to event handlers, so you probably coded yours wrong—but we can't really tell because there isn't enough code in your question to suggest how to fix things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `button_up`, `button_down` and `test` functions are not bound methods. Therefore, they do not get the `self` parameter. The value being passed as `self` is actually an Event object. Since you use `self` in the functions, I would recommend changing them to being bound methods. I assume the code you posted is in the `__init__` method. If so, change the last three lines to:

```
self.Scrolledtext1.bind("<Button-1>", self.button_down)
self.Scrolledtext1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.button_up)
self.Button2.configure(command=self.test)
```

And move the three functions to be members of the class:

```
def button_down(self, event):
    global s
    s = self.Text1.index('@%s,%s wordstart' % (event.x, event.y))

def button_up(self, event):
    global e
    e = self.Text1.index('@%s,%s wordend' % (event.x, event.y))


def test(self, event):
    print(self.Scrolledtext1.get(s,e))
```

### Example

This is how your class should look afterwards. The three event handler functions are all inside the class.

```
class YourClassName:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # initialization code
        # ...

        self.Scrolledtext1.bind("<Button-1>", self.button_down)
        self.Scrolledtext1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.button_up)
        self.Button2.configure(command=self.test)

    def button_down(self, event):
        global s
        s = self.Text1.index('@%s,%s wordstart' % (event.x, event.y))

    def button_up(self, event):
        global e
        e = self.Text1.index('@%s,%s wordend' % (event.x, event.y))


    def test(self, event):
        print(self.Scrolledtext1.get(s,e))
```

Comment: I tried it, but  File "lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: button_up() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

Comment: You made the functions methods of the class, right? And you changed the `ScrolledText.bind` from `button_up` to `self.button_up`? That error sounds like `button_up` is still an unbound function.

Answer (score -1):

Try to pass evt instead of self in your function

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33646275)